# How to display ajax success response inside div with javascript

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am writing one ajax call and collect the response from controller. I want to show that response(jsp) to one particular div. Please help me, how to put response div to current page div.Below is the code:

```
function openSocietyTab(divName, parentTabName, subTabName)
    {
        debugger;
        var i;
          var x = document.getElementById(divName); 
          var parentTempId = parentTabName;
          var tempId = subTabName;
           $.ajax({

              type : "GET",
                url : "/ApartmentAdda/"+parentTempId+"/"+tempId,
                data : {x:tempId},
                timeout : 100000,
                success : function(x) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("SUCCESS: ", x);
                    // here i want to display x into divName div.(x is the jsp view which i am getting from controller)

                },  
                error : function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                }
          });
    }
```

I am calling this javascript function on button click:

```
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button dropbtnInr" onclick="openSocietyTab('tabToOpen','societyService','houseTab')">Houses</button><br>
```

and tabToOpen is the div on which I want to open ajax response jsp.

Comment: You may want to edit your tags, I think that it would have been more suitable to just use `javascript`, 'html' and optionally 'jquery'. Hibernate, spring and jsp have nothing to do with this process.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but since you only want to display a certain div then I'd suggest you to use the `hidden` class to hide and show the div.

For example if the div has id="tabToOpen" and you are using jQuery then it would be:

```
$(#tabToOpen).addClass('hidden');  
$(#tabToOpen).removeClass('hidden');
```

If you are not using jQuery then try:

```
var theInfoDiv = document.getElementsById('tabToOpen');  
theInfoDiv.classList.add('hidden');  
theInfoDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
```

Comment: Hi Christos..thank you for answering my question but it is partially woks. I want to open one jsp design inside tabToOpen div.
var theInfoDiv = document.getElementsById('tabToOpen');  ---- we are getting the div with id tabToOpen. but now want to open jsp inside this div. So how can we do that?

in console.log("SUCCESS: ", x); -- i can successfully display the external jsp. I am getting it in x variable. 

Now just want to display x inside toToOpen div

Comment: Please write the code in your comment in your question as edit, it's hard to read it. If you return html code along with the data and you want to display that, then try with the `innerHTML`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp It would help if  edit your answer with an example of what you are getting on success of the ajax call.